# Silverstripe 3.1 one to one relation

Tags: silverstripe

What is the best way to manage a 1:1 relation in Silverstripe with the following example.  It's easy to add the $db fields to the page, but if I want to maintain it as a separate Dataobject, whats the best way?  (Lot of info on 1:many, but not 1:1) eg.

```
class CarSpecs extends Dataobject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Make' => 'Text',
        'Model' => 'Text',
        'ModelDescription' => 'Text',
        'NumberOfSeats' => 'VarChar(20)',
        'Price' => 'Currency'
}

class Car extends Page {
    private static $has_one = array('CarSpecs' => 'CarSpecs');
}
```

Silverstripe automatically adds a page ID to the database table in Car to find CarSpecs, but what about in Carspecs? How to I add and edit the related fields in the CMS.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `belongs_to`

Defines a 1-to-1 relationship with another object, which declares the other end of the relationship with a 
corresponding $has_one. A single database column named `<relationship-name>ID` will be created in the object with the 
`$has_one`, but the $belongs_to by itself will not create a database field. This field will hold the ID of the object 
declaring the `$belongs_to`.

Similarly with $has_many, dot notation can be used to explicitly specify the `$has_one` which refers to this relation. 
This is not mandatory unless the relationship would be otherwise ambiguous.

```php
<?php

class Team extends DataObject {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Coach' => 'Coach'
    );
}

class Coach extends DataObject {

    private static $belongs_to = array(
        'Team' => 'Team.Coach'
    );
}
```

### edit:

Based on your comment and a re-read of the question I'm guessing your wanting a way to edit CarSpecs separately from the CarPages, in which case you're looking for the [ModelAdmin](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/modeladmin) with something like:

```php
<?php

class CarSpecsAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'CarSpecs'
    );

    private static $url_segment = 'CarSpecs';

    private static $menu_title = 'Car Specs Admin';
}
```

Comment: So as in my example, the CarSpecsID in the Car database table will be the same ID in the CarSpecs table?  If so how do I edit the CMS fields in my example, is there a silverstripe method/function to relate it, is gridfield needed here??? so can a new Textfield know the relation???

Comment: Yes you need a gridfield to manage the relations. Have a peek on this page: http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/tutorials/dataobject_relationship_management/ also silverstripe has now video tutorials on relationship management that can be found here http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/